# Preserve white spaces while normalizing on keywords in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, querydsl

I have the following template that converts my keywords into lowercase. When I search on one-worded keywords like `Minnesota` and `Dallas` the search result is accurate.

However, anything with a white space in it returns inaccurate results. If I try searching for "North Texas" I expect the search to return all documents containing "North Texas".

I think the keyword tokenizer is breaking two words into one-each based on the whitespace. How do I preserve the whitespace while using `normalizers`?

```
{
    "template": "myTemplate_*",
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "refresh_interval": "15s",
            "translog": {
                "durability": "async"
            }
        },
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "word_joiner": {
                    "type": "word_delimiter",
                    "preserve_original": true
                }
            },
            "tokenizer": {
                "queryparam_tokenizer": {
                    "type": "pattern",
                    "pattern": "&"
                }
            },
            "normalizer": {
                "normalizer_keyword": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding",
                        "word_joiner"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": false
            }
        },
        "account": {
            "dynamic": "false",
            "properties": {
                "city": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "null_value": " Null",
                    "normalizer": "normalizer_keyword"
                },
                "state": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "null_value": " Null",
                    "normalizer": "normalizer_keyword"
                },
                "region": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "null_value": " Null",
                    "normalizer": "normalizer_keyword"
                },
                "area": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "null_value": " Null",
                    "normalizer": "normalizer_keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried to add a `word_delimeter` filter with `preserve_original` set to `true` and it throws me an error.

```
"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Custom normalizer [normalizer_keyword] may not use filter [word_joiner]"},"status":400}
```

Note: I am using `query_string` to perform wildcard matches in ES.

Comment: The sence of Normalizers is the the produce only one token. word_delimiter produces more then one token for "North Texas", if you want to normalize the withspace use pattern_replace token filter. What do you expect from word_delimiter?

Comment: @KarstenR. I was just exploring `word_delimiter` I guess and I do not have any specific needs for it. How would I use the `pattern_replace` token filter to normalize my `whitespaces`?

Comment: do you have the need to normalize whitespace? If yes, you can replace \s+ with one " ".